# String not returning anything

Tags: java, string, if-statement

So im writing a program which prints out the season according to a date set using parameters. My problem is that by using public static String with the corresponding return statements, the program does not print out anything when executing

```
public class Lab06 {

  public static void main (String [] args) {
     season(12, 15);

  }

  public static String season(int month, int day) {
     if ((((month == 12) && (day >= 16))) || (((month <= 2) && (day <= 31)))
      || (((month == 3) && (day <= 15)))) {
        return "Winter";
     }
     else if ((((month == 3) && (day >= 16)) || ((month == 4 || month == 5) && (day <= 31))
      || ((month == 6) && (day <= 15)))) {
        return "Spring";
     }
     else if ((((month == 6) && (day >= 16)) || ((month == 7 || month == 8) && (day <= 31))
      || ((month == 9) && (day <= 15)))) {
        return "Summer";
     }
     else {
        return "Fall";
     }
  }
```

With the current set parameter, its supposed to return "Fall", but when i execute the program it does nothing.

I also when ahead and tried using public static void with the correspondent system.out.print statements just to check if my problem lied within my if statements.

```
public class Lab06 {

   public static void main (String [] args) {
      season(12, 15);

   }

   public static void season(int month, int day) {
      if ((((month == 12) && (day >= 16))) || (((month <= 2) && (day <= 31)))
       || (((month == 3) && (day <= 15)))) {
         return "Winter";
      }
      else if ((((month == 3) && (day >= 16)) || ((month == 4 || month == 5) && (day <= 31))
       || ((month == 6) && (day <= 15)))) {
         return "Spring";
      }
      else if ((((month == 6) && (day >= 16)) || ((month == 7 || month == 8) && (day <= 31))
       || ((month == 9) && (day <= 15)))) {
         return "Summer";
      }
      else {
         System.out.print("Fall");
      }
   }
```

By doing that my program did indeed work as intended so there is nothing wrong with my if statements

For this assignment i need the use public static String

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Change `season(12, 15);` to `System.out.print(season(12, 15));`

Comment: Oh wow it was that simple. Thanks man, hopefully it doesn't drop me some points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling a method in java, like

```
season(12, 15);
```

Causes absolutely nothing in the way of output. Try this instead:

```
System.out.print(season(12, 15));
```

Answer (score 1):

you only returned the value, but did not do anything about it.

Use

```
System.out.print(season(12,15));
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java we call method like 
    season(12,15); 
And your method is returning a String value but in your case you want to print that value, so you can do that in two ways-

First approach-

```
String returnValue = season(12,15);

System.out.println("return value" + returnValue);  // By this approach you can use your store value later also.
```

Second approach-

```
System.out.println( season(12,15));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a return type mismatch:

```
static void
...
return "Winter";
```

You ned a `static String` instead to return a String value.

You can then print out the value as a result of the function.

```
String season = season(12, 15);
System.out.println(season);
```

or simply just

```
System.out.println(season(12, 15));
```

You also print from the function in the second example. This should be tuned into a return to pass it back to the caller.